# How to dynamically replace a variable by its value in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a problem scenario as explained below.

```
 DECLARE @WhereClause VARCHAR(MAX)
 SET @WhereClause = 'Address = ''A'' AND AppId = @AppId'
 --I have values like below:
 SET @AppId = '123333' 
 SET @param = @AppId --This information I retrieve from database
```

Now I want to replace the @AppId in the @whereClause by its value 123333. I only have information about variable @param and I can use @param to replace the @AppId as I am getting the @param variable from database dynamically.

SET @WhereClause = REPLACE(@WhereClause, @param ,'???')

I need something that could replace AppId by its value in @WhereClause. I have the @param variable which I can use to know which variable needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [sp_executesql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) function. This should do what you need:

```
Declare @sql varchar(max); set @sql = ' ... ';

set @sql = @sql + @WhereClause;
declare @Params nvarchar(max); set @Params = N'@ID nchar(5)';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @ParmDefinition, @ID = @Appid;
```